# Как установить Chilkat на Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Всем привет!
В гугле ничего не нашел ВООБЩЕ. Офф. инструкцию по установке не понял. Суть такая: перехожу с Visual Studio на Code::Blocks. На Visual Studio есть такой шедевр как EASendMail для отправки email по ssl, на Code::Blocks нашел либу для отправки мейл - ChilKat. Но вот проблема, я не могу её установить. Да что там не могу, я даже не знаю. Пробывал что то, но пробывал давно, так что даже не помню что делал. Суть та же - инструкций нигде нет, на ютубе тоже. Помогите, пожалуйста, обьясните как праильно её установить?

UPD: Версия MinGW:
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm-1)

Comment: На сайте написано, что часть библиотеки платная. Уверены, что часть, отвечающая за почту, бесплатная?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat оу, я не видел. А можете тогда посоветовать какие есть библиотеки для работы с ssl email на code:blocks? curl не в счёт. Тоже не заладилось с ним. Неделю мучался.

Comment: Недавно сам искал и ничего толкового не нашел.